# Inverse of a Bijective Bivariate quadratic function or polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, inverse

I am looking for some general way to invert a bijective quadratic polynomial of the form
$$
f(x,y)=A_0x+A_1x^2+Axy+B_0y+B_1y^2+Byx
$$
where the coefficients may or may not be in the same ring as the variables and either or both of them may or may not be commutative, which is why I left $A_1,B_1$ in there. If $x,y$ are in a commutative ring, they should be zero.
Any restrictions would be nice as well.